# try catch error Slim Framework 3

Tags: php, try-catch, slim

I'm using Slim framework 3, and I'm kinda new to this framework. So maybe there's a specific way to do this and I don't know.

Here's what I have:

```
$app->post('/URL', function ($request, $response, $arguments) {

try{

    //my code
}
catch (Exception $e){
   $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
}

});
```

And when I run it, it says  **syntax error, unexpected '{'**  in the `try` line.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this your entire code? Since you got a syntax error, it's probably not related to the framework itself.

Comment: The error is not in the code above.  If the error is in fact reported on that file, it's likely something above that block of code.

Comment: Meanwhile I solved it. It was somekind of hidden special character between `try` and `{`
But thanks :)